# Json-View not working for reactive types (Spring Web mvc, with reactive type support)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, flux, reactive, json-view

Have a problem with JsonView support for reactive types in spring web mvc application. Spring 5 supports reactive types with ReactiveTypeHandler + taskExecutor configuration in WebMvcConfig. The data is returning, but the JsonView is ignored and all the data will be passed to the subscriber. Here is the code example:

```
@JsonView(Views.All.class)
@GetMapping(value = "/items", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE )
public Flux<Item> getItems() {
    return itemService.getItems();
}
```

For non reactive types the JsonView is processing by org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyAdviceChain#processBody via JsonViewResponseBodyAdvice. 
But it doesn't trigger in ReactiveTypeHandler for reactive types.

I know that in spring web reactive the json view can be supported by setting hint Jackson2CodecSupport.JSON_VIEW_HINT via ServerResponse, but this code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/items", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE )
Mono<ServerResponse> getItems() {
    return ServerResponse
                .ok()
                .hint(Jackson2CodecSupport.JSON_VIEW_HINT, Views.All.class)
                .body(itemService.getItems(), Item.class);
}
```

won't work in mvc, it will throw the unsupported exceprtion HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException since org.springframework.http.converter.GenericHttpMessageConverter#canWrite for this target type is false.

Is there any hint or idea how to use jsonViews mechanism for reactive types on web mvc? (Can't change the web mvc to reactive web in the project, cause of some requirements)
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Found that as workaround the issue can be fixed with MappingJacksonValue.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/items", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE )
public Flux<MappingJacksonValue> getItems() {
    return itemService.getItems()
           .map(e -> {
               MappingJacksonValue value = new MappingJacksonValue(e);
               value.setSerializationView(Views.All.class);
               return value;
            });
}
```

Not sure that this behavior of spring is correct, can it be consider as a bug and needed to create an issue on webmvc?